# OSX Mobile Broadband API for broadband connection management

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, osx-mavericks, mobile-broadband-api

Does Mac OS X provide an API that is similar to the Windows Mobile Broadband API? In particular, I'm looking for an API that can be used to manage broadband connections over modem devices.

Thanks!